# how can I retrieve data from Firebase in web using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, web

How can I retrieve data from Firebase and add to html page? 
and, How can I open new html pages automatically to add the data I was retrieving it? 
example: 
I have this course from firbase:
[image]

this key I was pushing it .
and I want my website like this course : 
[image: courses image]

When I click this courses I want to see all data about this course like this : 
[image: description coursers]

Can anyone help me ?!
I won't like this style just I want to know how can i retrieve data and add it in new html pages in the same style in all courses  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve data from a firebase realtime database like so:

```js
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Get a database reference to our posts
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("path/of/your/information");

// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

See [Official Documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

> Note: requires Node.js / npm

Comment: thank you ! but I want to know  how can I create pages of courses automatically  and add this information from firebase .